# Clicking on the taskbar clock does nothing in my Windows 11... i

Tags: taskbar, calendar, windows-11

I think this is worked after fresh install, but I am not sure. Anyway, now if I click on the taskbar clock nothing happens.

I would like to get a calendar (I do know, Outlook events removed), I mean the simple calendar to allow me to see next weeks days, as it shown in the picture below.

What I had misconfigured?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by Action Center being disabled. It can be disabled via 3 methods:

1. Registry Setting - Open regedit.exe, Navigate to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer and then remove the "DisableActionCenter" item.
2. Group Policy - open gpedit.msc, Navigate to "User Configuration" > "Administrative Templates" > "Start Menu and Taskbar" > "Remove Notifications and Action Center" and set it to Disabled if it was enabled or leave at "Not Configured" if it was not set.
3. WinAero Tweaker - Find the setting named "Disable Action Center" and uncheck it.

Make sure you check all 3, I had it disabled in both registry and WinAero Tweaker and enabling in registry did not fix it. I also had to enable it in WinAero. Once done, restart explorer.exe or reboot and it will be fixed.

Also on a related note: If you have set the registry setting or WinAero setting to enable "Classic Start Menu" in Win 11, it will break the start menu as well as the "quick access" menu appearing when clicking on the Wireless/Volume/Battery icons. Once changes are made, restart explorer.exe or reboot.

1. Registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
   and remove the "Start_ShowClassicMode" item.
2. WinAero: Uncheck the "Enable Classic taskbar and start menu"

Answer (score 5):

Basically unlike Windows 10, in windows 11 this date and time pop-up is minimized. You just have to click on the maximize button there, as below. Even I was searching for a solution while reading this article and realized the same while reading the article about this simple solution !!

[image]

Comment: Whoa. I did not see it coming. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes I encounter this issue as well.

I don't know what causes this and couldn't find a permenant solution but as a quick fix.

- Find and kill `explorer.exe` from Task Manager (Taskbar will dissappear)
- At the same window's menu File/New Task
- Type explorer then click ok

Taskbar will re-appear and calendar should work again.

Comment: Thx, tried, it does not help in my case

Comment: This worked for me, instead of killing Explorer and starting it again, I found that if you selected Windows Explorer in the Task Manager, there's a button that shows up top called Restart Task, and clicking that fixed this issue for me. Can't believe it's 2023 and Microsoft still can't make a stable operating system.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyway, now if I click on the taskbar clock nothing happens.

Clock misbehavior can be with by repairing the app, or fixed with DISM and SFC.

(A) Repair the Clock:

Start, Settings, Apps, Apps and Features:  Scroll down to Clock, Click on the 3 dots, Advanced Features.  Scroll down the right side and click on Repair and then Reset.

I would restart the computer after this.

(B) If Clock Repair fails, run DISM and SFC.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Helpful article in this (includes the steps above that I use).

[Windows 11 Clock App not loading](https://www.technipages.com/windows-11-how-to-fix-the-clock-app-not-loading)

> Windows 11 Clock App Won’t Load Repair and Reset the Clock App
> Navigate to Settings. Click on Apps. Select Apps & features. Locate
> the Clock app. Click on the three dots and select Advanced options.
> Then hit the Repair button

Comment: many thx....there is no Clock app in the list when I navigate to Apps & features. Total of 94 apps found...

Comment: I see the Clock App on both my Windows 11 Computers.   77 Apps and Clock is underneath Camera. So now run DISM and SFC (see my post) and restart after that. If not there, Repairs get more aggressive.

Comment: many thx. Now I executed all, exactly as you wrote in your answer, nothing changed. Btw before I run sfc and dism ... /scanhealth neither found anything, and reported all is OK. What I've noticed, that I also did not get the notifications, although notification setting is ON, and focus is OFF, so it is definitely have to do something the Clocks and Alarms app...

Comment: I was beyond skeptical that the dism/sfc process would work...but it did! Thanks for giving me my sanity back.

Comment: @g.pickardou Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue and none of these "fixes" work for me either.

Comment: I found a solution! See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was not limited to the Calendar. Many items were not working as expected such as the "Add Bluetooth or other device" wizard, Action Center, volume control popup,  tray notifications, and perhaps a whole lot more.

I suspect this was a result of me moving my user profile from a slightly older version of Windows 10 to a fresh install of a newer one (Windows 10 LTSC 2019 to 2021)

The following command fixed the problem for my user profile.  Run this in the Windows PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage | % { Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml" -verbose }
```

Note: The command may generate some errors due to some items being in use.  In my case that was not an issue and I was able to ignore it.

This above command will read a list of all installed app packages for your user and reinstall them.  The key part of that being the `DisableDevelopmentMode` and `Register` flags which will repair any corrupted packages.  This specific command works only on the user level.

Read more about `Get-AppxPackage` and `Add-AppxPackage` on Microsoft's documentation site to understand what it does:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Answer (score 1):

Right click on clock in taskbar > Adjust Date Time
Scroll down and add additional clock and save. Then if u click on the taskbar clock you will see the  time.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and managed to fix it.

1. Open Regedit
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`
   If there is an option saying `DisableNotificationCenter` make sure the data is set as `0`. Mine was `1`, for some reason. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same, and freaking disliked the answers above.

So here is the solution, because even paid microsoft representatives cannot answer that.

Follow every steps carefully, or you will break your system ( no joke ) We will play in the Registry Editor.

- Disclaimer, if you make a bad move, or that you didnt backup your original Registry, ***NOT*** ***MY*** ***PROBLEM*** *

---

1. Press **Win + R** to open the Run dialog box
2. Type ''**RegEdit**'' and press Enter to open the '**Registry Editor**'.
3. Navigate to the following, ***EXACTLY*** ( or you **WILL** break your system if you change anything **not related** to my troubleshooting )  ;
4. **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced**
5. Look for a **DWORD** value named '**ShowClock**' or similar. If you can't find it, you might need to create it. If you can't see it, heres how to create it ;

*5. A) **Right click** on a **blank space** in the ***\Advanced** folder, then click **New**

6. You will now see different choices, but you will have to click this **exact** value --­> '**DWORD 32 bits**'
7. Add it, you will not break anything after clicking left click in a blank space since the default hexadecimal value is set to 0, then right click on it, rename it exactly like that '' **ShowClock** ''.
8. Once renamed, right click on it again, ***Edit***.
9. Change the Binary Value from **0**, to **1**. Then press **OK**
10. ***Problem Solved.***

Comment: I dont have that, but my Clock is still visible.

Comment: From user XDraZeN, he wasn't able to post a comment and wanted to write the following under my solution, so I'll add it as a comment for him instead of pushing his comment as an edit ; 

XDraZeN : SORRY I DO NOT HAVE REPUTATION FOR UPVOTE OR ADD COMENTS, BUT I TRIED ALL OTHER METHODS HERE, AND ONLY THIS ONE WORKED. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score -1):

I'm using 42" TV screen and I changed my display settings to be able to read the menus from the sofa. However, these changes ruined my user experience of the calendar.
So I had to roll them back to solve this issue:
Open system settings -> display -> scale and resolution. And change both of these valus back to the recommended ones.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just click the little up arrow on the right after you click on the clock.